# Handling newlines when reading a file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv

My friends, I have an issue that I hope you can help me. So..Here is my code:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"convidados" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableArray* pointStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];

for(int idx = 0; idx < [pointStrings count]; idx++)
{

    NSString* currentPointString = [pointStrings objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]]];

    NSString *nome = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *email = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSString *website = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSString *telefone = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:3]];
    NSString *empresa = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:4]];
    NSString *cidade = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:5]];

    NSDictionary *registro = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nome, email , telefone, empresa, website, cidade, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nome", @"email", @"telefone", @"empresa", @"website", @"cidade", nil]];

    [PessoaDAO adicionar:registro];

    [arr removeAllObjects];
    [arr release];

}
```

My csv file:

```
Usuario1# Usuario1@gmail.com# http://facebook.com/Usuario1# 99999999#Company# Cidade
Usuario2# Usuario2@gmail.com# http://Usuario2.com# 737373773# Company# Fortaleza
Usuario3# Usuario3@gmail.com# http://Usuario3.com.br# 83838484# Company Solutions# City
```

The problem is when the line below is executed is recognized 7 objects when the right is only 3. I believe thats because the " newlineCharacterSet " them add a " , " and confuses the execution.

```
NSMutableArray* pointStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];
```

NSMutableArray pointStrings execution:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x1c586990>(
Usuario1# Usuario1@gmail.com# http://facebook.com/Usuario1# 99999999#Company# City,
,
Usuario2# Usuario2@gmail.com# http://Usuario2.com# 737373773# Company# City,
,
Usuario3# Usuario3@gmail.com# http://Usuario3.com.br# 83838484# Company# City,
,

)
```

Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: Why do you do this -- `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",someValue]` -- rather than just assigning the value to the result variable?  It's simply wasted motion.  And unnecessary obfuscation.

Comment: And if you rearranged your list of key values you'd have no need to even decode your `arr` array (which is being unnecessarily converted into an NSMutableArray).  I'm thinking you copied code you do not understand.

Comment: Because I use that variables in the next.

Comment: To do that:NSDictionary *registro = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nome, email , telefone, empresa, website, cidade, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nome", @"email", @"telefone", @"empresa", @"website", @"cidade", nil]];

    [PessoaDAO adicionar:registro];

Not influence in the issue.

Comment: That's what I said -- just pass the array directly to `initWithObjects` and rearrange the key list.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because the file you are using was created in Windows which [uses two characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`CR+LF`) at the end of a line. Your code splitting your lines at `CR` and then splitting again at `LF` which creates an empty line.

Just check if the count of `arr` is less than 6, or the length of `currentPointString` is 0 and if so continue:

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < [pointStrings count]; idx++) {

    NSString *currentPointString = [pointStrings objectAtIndex:idx];
    if ([currentPointString length] == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    NSMutableArray *arr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];
    if ([arr count] < 6) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

This will also take care of cases where there is a blank line in the file to begin with.

Comment: @LucasMacambas -- Be sure to observe my comments about using `initWithFormat` or you'll have serious leaks in your code.

Answer (score 0):

'csv' is an acronym for 'comma separated values', your data (as shown) is separated by spaces,  not commas.

Comment: Actually it's separated by `#`, which he is splitting by.

Comment: I think the point was that this is not, by definition, a CSV file since it does not have "Comma Separated Values".

Answer (score 0):

Mostly unrelated to your bug (whatever it is) --

```
NSArray* arr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSDictionary *registro = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:arr forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nome", @"email", @"website", @"telefonee", @"empresa", @"cidade", nil]];
```

The code formerly between those two lines is unnecessary, as is the [arr removeAllObjects].  And the above eliminates the need for the [arr release].

(And if you don't remove the bogus `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", ...` calls you're leaking a lot of storage.)

(Note that I provide this largely because (by doing copy/paste without really knowing what you're doing) you've gotten your code too complex for you to understand it.  By simplifying you can better zero in on problems.)